# Trying to make client-specific documents with a single master template

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

**A bit of background:** My company works with several clients that require we send them documents branded with their logos. For example, Company A will receive documents with headers, footers, and contact information specific to Company A. Company B will receive the same kind of document branded for Company B, and so on. The documents are standardized enough that about 90% of the Quick Parts used are overlapping.

Currently, we have a template for each company (about 8 of them) in two different languages (for a total 16 templates), which works fine on the user's end. The trouble is that any maintenance on my end requires that I edit each template individually, which is unnecessarily lengthy and leaves more room for error.

**What I would like to do** is to reduce these 16 into 2 templates, one for either language. I'd like the user to be prompted when opening a new document to select one of the companies (e.g. from a dropdown list or a stereo button). That company's headers, footers, and contact information would then be automatically inserted into the document.

So far, I've been able to store all the headers, footers, and AutoText into my Building Blocks gallery. What I'm struggling with is figuring out how to construct an element that would:

1. Prompt the user to select from among the 8 available companies.
2. Based on that selection, insert the appropriate Building Blocks at the correct locations.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?